# fix and int function not working in SAP crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using SAP crystal report with WPF App. when i use int or fix function in formula field is not returning correct value.

int(({Reports_Model_ReportModel.TotalWorks}/60))

or

fix(({Reports_Model_ReportModel.TotalWorks}/60))

I want return should be integer value like- **200/60 =3 instead of 3.333333333**.

can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi to get just the integer part of a division you should use the div function using the back slash instead of the slash

```
{Reports_Model_ReportModel.TotalWorks}\60
```

this is the result: 200\60 = 3

Comment: uff... this is my mistake , your answer is right but would return wrong value in case of when 3.55 (will return 4 instead of 3)

Comment: And you have the answer to that?

Comment: we should use CSTR(({BioReports_Model_ReportModel.TotalWorks}\60),0,'')

Comment: From what you write if you have 3.49 you want 3 as result and if it is 3.51 you want 4?! That you maybe better use the Round() function round({Reports_Model_ReportModel.TotalWorks}\60)